# Piano keys to key stroke conversion

Tags: keyboard, piano

Recently, I've set my sights on producing music online through digital piano softwhere, I'm aiming to play virtual piano keys that translate into keystrokes on my computer. While I've seen various programs compensating for the absence of physical piano keys by utilizing keyboard strokes, my aim is to reverse this process and have my piano produce keystrokes based on the specific piano keys I play.

However, I find myself at a loss as to where to start on this project, and I would greatly appreciate your guidance on how I could bring this idea to creation.

Here are the specific areas I'm seeking assistance with:

Acquiring Output Results: I'm uncertain about the approach to obtain the output results from my computer system when the piano is played. I can see that my computer is connected to the piano as well as notices my inputs, but I am unsure as to where the outputs are going and how I can harness them.

Data Interpretation: I'm interested in understanding how to develop a program that can interpret the data received from the piano keys and translate it into corresponding keyboard keystrokes. I'm not asking for code to be writen for me, but a place where I can do this.

Keystroke Simulation: Additionally, I need insights into creating a program that can simulate pressing the appropriate keys on the keyboard when a specific keystroke value is received from the piano. This in turn would play the notes on the online piano keyboard.

Your expertise and insights would be very much valuable in helping me understand the necessary steps and components required for this project. Your assistance in shedding light on the technical aspects and potential tools to achieve this would be greatly appreciated.

I've made efforts to locate an application capable of recognizing my piano, and came across something called FL Studio. It successfully detected and interpreted the piano's values. I'm contemplating a process where I can capture the outputs from this program and direct them into another application that can seamlessly convert them into keystrokes, subsequently playing them as they are received.

If it at all helps, I'm on a windows 11 computer my Piano is a CASIO CT-X700 and I have connected the two using a USB B and USB A cable.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.